# Favorite queries not showing on data.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, data-explorer

I wrote some queries, saved them, and marked them as favorites.  But when I choose "favorites" I see all queries.  I can find mine, and when I do I see them marked as favorite, but I cannot find them when choosing favorite.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're choosing the [favorite tab on the home page](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=favorite), which shows queries anyone has favorited:

[image: Screenshot]

You need to choose the [favorite tab on your profile](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/91/michael-mrozek?order_by=favorite) to show only your favorites:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you.  I now see that the "Favorites" on the main page is to show questions that are ranked by how many of all the users set them as favorites.  Makes sense now!